# cmake get find_package to find package specific variables

Tags: c, cmake

So, I want to create a C library that can be installed in such a way that it is easily usable in other projects with the `find_package` function in cmake. Specifically, I want a project, say called foo, to be accessible like this:

```
find_package (foo-1.0 REQUIRED)

message ("!--   foo found version \"${FOO_VERSION}\"")
message ("!--   foo include path \"${FOO_INCLUDE_DIRS}\"")
message ("!--   foo libraries \"${FOO_LIBRARIES}\"")
```

Then, those variables could be used with targets in other cmake projects, like:

```
add_executable (example example.c)
target_include_directories (example PRIVATE "${FOO_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
target_link_libraries (example PRIVATE "${FOO_LIBRARIES}")
```

My question is though:

1. In what way should a static or shared c library be installed to be findable by `find_package` (aka what destination is needed).
2. How do i expose variables like `FOO_LIBRARIES` such that the `find_package` function will expose them in the project calling `find_package`?

Comment: You ask about packaging the project in CMake, but your code shows no packaging attempt. Have your read some tutorials on this topic? E.g. the one on CMake official site: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-packages.7.html.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you, i did not know there was specific guide on packaging, i only saw per function guide before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do this. Basically you have to have `.cmake.in` files that act as a template for a config file and a config version file for the end package. `find_package` will look at the following places for cmake config and version files:

```
${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include/${LIBKOF_NAMED_VERSION}
${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/${LIBKOF_NAMED_VERSION}
```

Where `LIBKOF_NAMED_VERSION` is the package folder, such as `foo-1.2`

`libkof` is the name of my package, and you can see how this is done below:

```
# This cmake is responsible for installing cmake config and other version
# files.

# This sets the package specific versioning
set(LIBKOF_MAJOR_VERSION 1)
set(LIBKOF_MINOR_VERSION 0)
set(LIBKOF_PATCH_VERSION 0)

# This allows easy creation of the directories within /usr/local or another install
# prefix
set(LIBKOF_NAMED_VERSION libkof-${LIBKOF_MAJOR_VERSION}.${LIBKOF_MINOR_VERSION})

# These statements will create the directories needed for installs
install(DIRECTORY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include/${LIBKOF_NAMED_VERSION})
install(DIRECTORY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/${LIBKOF_NAMED_VERSION})

# This tracks the name of the in files used to generate the package cmake files
set(LIBKOF_CONFIG_FILE libkof-config.cmake.in)
set(LIBKOF_CONFIG_VERSION_FILE libkof-config-version.cmake.in)

# The configure_file statements will exchange the variables for the values in this cmake file.
configure_file(${LIBKOF_CONFIG_FILE} libkof-config.cmake @ONLY)
configure_file(${LIBKOF_CONFIG_VERSION_FILE} libkof-config-version.cmake @ONLY)

# Installs to the output locations so they can be found with find_package()
install(FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/libkof-config-version.cmake DESTINATION include/${LIBKOF_NAMED_VERSION})
install(FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/libkof-config.cmake DESTINATION lib/${LIBKOF_NAMED_VERSION})
```